# CC.net - One or more dlls have changed

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm getting error - `One or more Dlls have change` stopping after cloning in git for 1 hour. We have been running `cc.net` with `hg` and now trying to migrate to `git`.

I'm getting this error , not sure how else to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to the fact that the first integration with git will get all mods :-(

download the latest dev release, it has been fixed.
The 1.8.5 version of CCNet will be out soon.

http://build.nauck-it.de/download/CruiseControl.NET-dev/